# Riddle for a fine Thursday Morning

Tags: riddle

You'll see me when there's an illegal action,
you'll hear me when the parents request.
I'm an answer to your daily question,
I'm an answer when you're stressed.

I am not a super hero,
nor your grandma undressed.
I'm beyond average,
but I'm not the best.

I am....?

Comment: "nor your grandma undressed" Oh my boy.

Comment: "Violence", because the answer to all the questions and the solution for  when I'm stressed is "Violence".

Comment: @Marius Violence does not solve problems at all =\

Comment: @Alex. If violence does not solve your problem you are not using enough. And just for the record...I was trying to be funny. Aparently I failed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it's

> Fine

You'll see me when there's an illegal action,

> People can get a fine for an illegal action

you'll hear me when the parents request.

> Parent: "Time to do the dishes." Kid: "Fine :(" (Thanks, Davie Brown)

I'm an answer to your daily question,

> "Fine" is a common answer to "How are you?"

I'm an answer when you're stressed.

> People often just say they're fine when they aren't but don't want to talk about it

I am not a super hero,
nor your grandma undressed.

> Pretty women can be called "fine," but I guess your grandma undressed doesn't qualify...

I'm beyond average,
but I'm not the best.

> Pretty much the definition of fine

Also

> Fine is in the riddle's title

Comment: "You'll hear me when the parents request." I guess "fine" fits with this where it's you agreeing to fulfill your parent's request. Parent: "Time to do the dishes." Kid: "Fine :("

Comment: Nicely done!  This is the answer

Comment: It's a good riddle, but in my opinion it's a bit unfortunate that all uses of fine except in the first clue are basically the same, namely okay. There are much more meanings of fine, e.g. delicate or not coarse.

Comment: @MOehm, I think OP wad going for [fine](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fine) with the "grandma undressed" bit.

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> Pizza ?

You'll see me when there's an illegal action,

> You eat pizza when you watch an action movie (and they always do a lot of illegal stuff)

you'll hear me when the parents request.

> "Hey kid, there is pizza for you in the kitchen, it's dinner time"

I'm an answer to your daily question,

> What I am going to eat today ? ---> pizza !

I'm an answer when you're stressed.

> Keep calm and eat a pizza

I am not a super hero,

> There is no pizza man

nor your grandma undressed.

> Pizza has cheese, grandma has not.

I'm beyond average,

> obvious

but I'm not the best.

> Pizza does not really fit here :/ PIZZA IS THE BEST !

Comment: Ha ha ha....This actually makes sense.  Ha ha ha.

Comment: Pizza has cheese, and what??

Answer (score 3):

How about

> Whistle

You'll see me when there's an illegal action,

> Someone may blow the whistle on you

you'll hear me when the parents request.

> Your parents may whistle for you to come

I'm an answer to your daily question,

> thinking on this one - the day whistles by?

I'm an answer when you're stressed.

> Whistle while you work

I am not a super hero,

> I know of no -Superwhistle

nor your grandma undressed.

> some people give a wolf-whistle to a pretty lady but not to your grandma undressed

I'm beyond average,

> With bells and whistles

but I'm not the best.

> a whistle-stop is a tiny stop on a trip

Comment: interesting thought, +1